# Is there an offline dictionary?

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, dictionary

Are there any off-line dictionaries available?

Comment: any particulare language?

Answer (score 23):

I would recommend **Artha**, It is an Offline dictionary, I find it really comprehensive and it also suggests you synonyms of the word you are looking up.
You can download Artha from **Ubuntu Software Centre**.

> Artha is a free cross-platform English
>   thesaurus that works completely
>   off-line and is based on WordNet

Website: http://artha.sourceforge.net

Comment: +1 but does it update the wordnet dictionaries?

Comment: Does it support any languages other than English?

Answer (score 8):

#### GoldenDict

I suggest GoldenDict a very powerful shell in which you will be able to install a great many dictionaries of various formats. Just for an English explanatory dictionary add goldendict-wordnet option.

To install goldendict and goldendict-wordnet in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install goldendict goldendict-wordnet
```

Comment: Thank you Alan for editing of my answer. I thought that for new Ubuntu users it is always easier to install apps from Ubuntu SC or Synaptic :)

Comment: it is much easier to use the software center.

Comment: I guess it's personal preference. I tend to encourage new users to use the terminal for installing apps, so that they can quickly familiarize themselves with it. But click to install is most certainly, always easier.

Comment: are there any up-to-date links to add dictionaries to Goldendict? the older links from their website are dead

Comment: are there other dictionaries to add to GoldenDict in the same way as the goldendict-wordnet option?