# Where can I find dictionaries for Opendict and Goldendict?

Tags: dictionary

Asking about good offline dictionaries in Ubuntu would have created a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/40807/47206) which got as answers only **Goldendict** and **Artha**.

Artha is ok but is limited to English as far as I can tell.
[image]

**I would like at least some more English and French dictionaries.**

I have also installed **Opendict** but it asks to add dictionaries. How to do it?
[image]

Many users recommend **Goldendict**, which comes with Wikipedia and to which I could add an [English dictionary](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/goldendict-wordnet),
[image]

but for dictionary sources we are redirected to an almost dead [website](http://goldendict.org/dictionaries.php): most of links are dead and/or in Russian.  I cannot download any dictionaries from [Babylon](http://www.babylon.com/free-dictionaries/) as they just give a link to download Babylon.exe no matter what "free-dictionary" I choose. I have extracted the exe file but no .bgl files inside (what am I missing here?).

Comment: This one might be useful as well! http://askubuntu.com/questions/339745/convert-wordlist-txt-files-to-make-them-compatible-and-working-in-goldendict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "WordNet 3" dictionary which is supported by GoldenDict. To install it: Extract the Zip file and put it somewhere in your system then do the following:
Edit>Dictionaries>Add>Then select the extracted folder and click "Apply".

You can download WordNet 3 from this link:
http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_goldendict/downloads/dictionaries/WordNet3.0_1.0.zip/

Here is a collection of dictionaries:
http://www.stardict.org/download.php

Comment: the "apt://" protocol/link (http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/goldendict-wordnet) contained in my question would install WordNet 3. thnx for the rest