# Free offline translator or dictionary

Tags: dictionary, translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an offline dictionary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40807/is-there-an-offline-dictionary)

I work on a computer without internet. I need a translator or dictionary, which can be easily installed without the Internet, and work offline.

Comment: What language, to what language, command line or gui?, please, be a bit more specific, I know many solutions to this but they're language specific sometimes

Comment: From English to Russian. Preferably GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Artha](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/artha/) it works offline.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. It's better to include the essential parts of the answer here. Thanks!